# (Unreal Engine) iOS Deployment Without Paid Developer Account Won't Work

Tags: unreal-engine4

For days now I am trying to find out what I'm doing wrong can't find the right solution.
I am new to the Unreal Engine and currently trying to figure out how all of it works. I downloaded the Epic Zen Garden and the Sun Temple example project off of the "Engine Feature Samples" and wanted to deploy them on my iPhone XR, but I can't. 
I looked through about 10 possible solutions but none of them really worked and somehow there are several ways to handle this matter so I wanted to ask you to eventually share your workflow regarding building apps on iOS using Unreal.

My setup:

Unreal 4.23 and 4.24 /
iMac 2017 with OS Catalina 10.15.1 /
iPhone XR with iOS 13.3 /
Xcode 11.3

As the title mentions, I am trying to find a solution without having to spend $99 for the Paid Developer Program.

What I did so far:
I've opened up Xcode and created a new project. I automatically signed in with my free developer account, used an bundle identifier and deployed the app on my iPhone. What happened now is that a provisioning profile and a certificate is created.
I then switched back to Unreal, opened the project settings -> iOS and used the same bundle identifier like the on in the Xcode project.
The mobile provision and certificate show "valid" and I also checkmarked them.

I then choose my device within Unreal under "Launch" and 2 error messages pop up saying "Provision not found" "Signing key not found". Why though? It shows up as "valid".
When I try to launch Launch -> Project Launcher -> iPhone -> I suddenly receive following error:

ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt '/Users/myName/Documents/Unreal Projects/SunTemple/Binaries/IOS/SunTemple.target'. Check that this target has been built.

So what am I doing wrong? This solution came up the most while searching for ways to handle this problem.

I would be thankful if anyone could share his steps.

Best regards
Daniel